# Error: Page is not found: menu.html (Onsen UI)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

After clicking login button, I want to access page.html. But it is not working properly. It gave an error. I used Sliding Menu page pattern in Onsen UI. This is the code of it. It properly worked when it was put in index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sliding_menu.css">

    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script>
      ons.bootstrap();
      ons.ready(function() {
        menu.openMenuMenu();
      });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page.html"  max-slide-distance="260px" type="push" var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Title</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
        <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button class="menu-closeMenu" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                    </ons-icon>Close
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <ons-list class="menu-list">
            <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
                New Post
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
                Bookmark
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                <ons-icon icon="fa-twitter"></ons-icon>
                Official Twitter
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>

        <br>

        <ons-list class="bottom-menu-list">
            <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                Settings
                <div class="notification menu-notification">3</div>
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                Help
            </ons-list-item>

            <ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                Send feedback
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>



    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<ons-template>` should be placed in `index.html` even if you display them from other page. Just leave them there. If that's not your problem, please provide more information.

Comment: Thank a lot for idea.I changed it as a separate menu.html file.it worked for me.